# Grafica de dos dataframes con ggplot2 en R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Tengo un dataframe, llamémoslo `DF`, en formato largo de la siguiente forma:

```
  Fecha     Pais               value
1   2015    Chile      1.03891170046699
2   2015    Colombia   0.997514840169031
3   2015    Chile      0.96307999965156
4   2015    Colombia   0.978805917146093
```

Y necesito hacer una gráfica de Barras donde las variables del eje horizontal es cada país y por cada país se tengan dos barras, una por cada valor. En el eje vertical estén los valores.

Intenté con el siguiente código:

```
bar_plot = ggplot(DF, aes(x=Pais, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Pero no funciona porque solo aparece una de las barras verticales.

¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente codigo produce una grafica como la siguiente espero sea lo que necesitas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
library(ggplot2)

#Leemos los datos. Nota: En los datos del ejemplo Chilte tiene 
#dos registros del 2015, cambie uno a 2013
df <- read.table(text = "
  Fecha     Pais               value
   2015    Chile      1.03891170046699
   2015    Colombia   0.997514840169031
   2015    Chile      0.96307999965156
   2015    Colombia   0.978805917146093
    ", header =T)

#Es muy importante que las variables con las que queremos agrupar
#sen factores para que ggplot las separe
df$Fecha <- as.factor(df$Fecha)

#Crear una variable para identificar las filas (id)
df<-df%>%
    group_by(Pais)%>%
    mutate(id = as.factor(1:n()))

#Agregamos el argumento fill dentro de aes para que ggplot separe 
#las columnas por fechas
ggplot(df, aes(x=Pais, y=value, fill= id)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero, yo fui la que me equivoqué poniendo ese dato en 2015, ambos países tienen 2 datos para ese año y lo que yo necesito es una gráfica como la que tu acabas de presentar, pero para los datos con esas características. Puedes ayudarme de nuevo?

Comment: Entonces tienes dos datos del 2015 para Colombia y Chile y quieres que aparezca una columna por dato? Hay algún diferenciador de estos datos, o algún orden en que tengas que aparecer?

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Lo que se me ocurre es crear una id para separar las columnas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí me sirvió... Sabes cómo podría cambiarle el color a las barras?

Comment: Al final de la grafica agrega `+scale_fill_manual("Nombre", values = c("green", "orange"))`. En el argumento `values` puedes pasar los colores que desees usar. Hay distintas maneras de usar colores en R como hexadecimal o esta con nombres... pero eso merece una pregunta aparte.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.